# How to solve Error: XMLHttpRequest error. in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, google-places-api, flutter-web

I want to use to Google places api and
I am trying to call this api but I am getting this. error

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

```
static Future<List<Result>?> searchPlaces(context, String query) async {
    String mapApiKey = "API_KEY";
    String _host = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json';
    final url = '$_host?query=$query&key=$mapApiKey';
    //
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    print(response.body);
    //
    if (response.statusCode == '200') {
      GPlacesSearch result = GPlacesSearch.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return result.results!;
    } else
      return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know which platform you are using, but I guess the solution would be to disable chrome web security.

If you are working on mac try the following steps

- Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp
- Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.
- Find '--disable-extensions'
- Add '--disable-web-security'

And if you are working on windows just search for how to disable web security for chrome

Comment: Do we need to delete '--disable-extensions'?

Comment: no you don't, just make sure to place '--disable-web-security' under it

Comment: also make sure to add comma after both, because sometimes it cause some issues when leaving them out

Comment: Will it work in production?

Comment: It is working for debug

Comment: You shouldn't face this issue in production, it should work fine

Comment: Not working for production. I have upload the release on github pages and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this url 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com' before your actual url e.g.

```
String baseUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com';
String actualUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json';
String finalUrl = "$baseUrl/$actualUrl";
```

```
static Future<List<Result>?> searchPlaces(context, String query) async {
    String mapApiKey = "YOUR_KEY_HERE";
    var _sessionToken = Uuid().v4();
    String _host =
        'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json';
    final url = '$_host?query=$query&key=$mapApiKey';
    //
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url);

    //
    GPlacesSearch result = GPlacesSearch.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    return result.results!;
  }
}
```